# How to verify that the property name of an object exists?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, jestjs, supertest

I am making jest tests for my project and I want to verify that the unique identifier of the blog posts is named *id*.

This is my mongoose db blog posts collection:

```
[
        {
          title: 'Breaking Ice',
          author: 'Mike Vasovsky',
          url: 'www.mikey.com',
          likes: 14,
          id: '5fe21b5931f6ae09d4cc58b6'
        }
]
```

My not finished part of the code:

```
test("verify id property name", async () => {
  const response = await api
    .get('/api/blogs')
  
  expect(...).toBeDefined("id")
})
```

Comment: i believe respnse is an array. `response.forEach(item => expect(item.id).toBeDefined());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, use a boolean.

```js
expect(response && response.every(blog => blog && blog.id)).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

This works too. And, for those who need a complete snippet.

```
test('verify id property name', async () => {
  const response = await api.get('/api/blogs');
  response.body.forEach(blog => {
    expect(blog.id).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```